# How to set eclipse to auto refresh projects?

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, eclipse-plugin, visual-studio-code

I am building an maven project on eclipse that runs on Tomcat 7.0. So far for Java coding I use of course Eclipse IDE. When it comes to writing HTML, CSS, JS, I love using VS Code.

So far as I now when I make changes on some HTML, CSS, JS files using Eclipse editor. Tomcat sees these changes, and when I refresh localhost, normally I will see the newest version of my HTML and other files.

Whilst when I use VS Code to make some changes, eclipse of course updates changed files, and I can see them on Eclipse editor. BUT when I refresh localhost, I see browser reading old HTML files (saw it in developer console). To prevent this from happening, every time I make a change using VS Code, I need to click on my project in eclipse and hit F5 (Refresh), which is annoying, and then refresh localhost on browser. Then I will see browser reading my newest files (new changes).

Is there any way for Eclipse to refresh project every time I make changes using VS Code?

I tried in Preferences > General > Workspace, to enable "Refresh on access" and "Refresh using native hooks or pooling". And it doesn't make an effect.

Is there some plugin for this or option in eclipse, or am I condemned to hit F5 thousand times?

Comment: Do you have automatic builds enabled? It would affect republishing.

Comment: @nitind yeap. In workspace options its called "Build automatically" and its enabled.

Comment: Normally, "Refresh using native hooks (Windows) or polling (Linux/macOS)" should do the job. Which OS do you use? Do you use the latest version of Eclipse (Oxygen)? Is auto refresh not work at all or is it only delayed? Polling means delayed refresh, especially for large projects or when the system is busy (see [source code](http://git.eclipse.org/c/platform/eclipse.platform.resources.git/tree/bundles/org.eclipse.core.resources/src/org/eclipse/core/internal/refresh/PollingMonitor.java)). [Native hooks for Linux and macOS are in development.](http://eclip.se/108697)

Comment: @howlger I am using Windows 10, with latest version of Eclipse. I didn’t know that thing for pooling. Auto-Refresh doesn’t work, when I use VS Code to edit code.

Comment: @curious95 Are these regular (non-derived, not linked, etc.) files of an Eclipse project? Will new files show up in the Project Explorer? Does the timestamp of files that have been edited with VS Code change?